# Tinybutstrong htmlconv=no

Tags: tinybutstrong

I have a variable that contains square brackets
e.g.

```
$myvar = '[my foo]';
```

in my html I have

```
[var.myvar;htmlconv=no;noerr]
```

for some reason the opening brackets [[ are being coming up in the html source as follows

```
&#91;my foo]
```

any reason why the opening brackets are being changed to html enties

I am using TBS Version  : 3.8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the opening bracket `[` is a way to protect your template from TBS tag injection. This is a normal TBS feature which is documented [here](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/support.php#faq_protect).

You can avoid this behavior using parameter `protect=no`.